# Running Shell script inside pig activity - Azure data factory

Tags: azure, apache-pig, azure-data-factory

Hi I have a shell script which i am trying to run it as a pig activity in azure data factory. The pig script content is

```
sh containername/testshell.ksh
```

And it throws **"No such file or directory"**. I tried using the full path as well but no luck.

Could someone give some input on how to give the correct path.

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://sqldair.azurewebsites.net/?p=201) could help you.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT Thanks for the attention. That link is about how to launch pig jobs from linux shell, mine is an inverse i am trying to run a shell script inside a pig script. And i am creating a ondemand hadoop cluster to perform the task

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do something that ADF isn't really designed for. You might be better off using a Custom Activity rather than a Pig job.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the shell script to blob storage and then invoke that script to pig or hive. Below are the steps.

Hive:

```
!sh hadoop fs -ls    
wasbs://contyaineName@StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/pathToScript/testshell.ksh`
```

Pig

```
sh hadoop fs -ls 
wasbs://contyaineName@StorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/pathToScript/testshell.ksh`
```

Answer (score 0):

try following Solution:

```
sh bash containername/testshell.ksh
```

and make sure you enter your shebang directive accordingly.